# correct Displaying of TreeView from ObjectArray

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

im creating a Tree View.

```
public void CreateTreeView1(TableInfo[] items)
    {
        treeView1.TabStop = false;
        TreeNodeCollection nodes = treeView1.Nodes;

        for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
        {
            TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode( items[i].Schemaname+"."+items[i].Tablename);
            newNode.Tag = items[i];
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(newNode);

            for (int j = 0; j < service.GibSpaltenNamen(items[i].Tablename).Length; j++)
            {
                newNode = new TreeNode(items[i].Columnname);
                newNode.Tag = items[j];
                treeView1.Nodes[i].Nodes.Add(newNode);
            }
        }
```

And the parameter TableInfo[] is an array of objects with: schemaname,tablename,columnname,description. All filled with informations
But while creating the TreeView dont make that sense.
I want it like this:

[image: Treeview]

Thanks Janik
        }

EDIT:

```
 public void CreateTreeView1(TableInfo[] items)
    {
        treeView1.TabStop = false;
        TreeNodeCollection nodes = treeView1.Nodes;

        foreach (TableInfo Tvalue in items)          
        {
            TreeNode newTNode = new TreeNode(Tvalue.Schemaname + "." + Tvalue.Tablename);
            newTNode.Tag = Tvalue;
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(newTNode);


            foreach (ColumnInfo Cvalue in Tvalue.Columns)
            {
                TreeNode newCNode = new TreeNode(Cvalue.Name);
                newCNode.Tag = Cvalue;
                newTNode.Nodes.Add(newCNode);
            }
        }           
    }
```

This is my Solution...

Comment: Could you sketch an image to show, how the data must be viewed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, that `TableInfo` looks like this:

```
class TableInfo
{
    public string SchemaName { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

you should group it first by `SchemaName` and `TableName`. Then, building of `TreeView` becomes very simple:

```
        treeView1.BeginUpdate();
        try
        {
            var nodes = items
                .GroupBy(_ => string.Format("{0}.{1}", _.SchemaName, _.TableName))
                .Select(_ => new TreeNode(
                    _.Key,
                    _.Select(info => new TreeNode(info.ColumnName)
                    {
                        Tag = info
                    })
                    .ToArray()))
                .ToArray();

            treeView1.Nodes.AddRange(nodes);
        }
        finally
        {
            treeView1.EndUpdate();
        }
```

Note, that I've omitted `Tag` initialization for top-level nodes, since they are grouping nodes.